# kibana 7.2 can't reach elasticsearch on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kibana-7

I'm testing the latest version of the Elastic Stack (7.2.0) and i can't seem to connect Kibana to Elasticsearch, but when i rollback to 6.8.1 it works. Any ideas ?

---

### Kibana Deploy & Service

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: *************
  labels:
    component: kibana
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: kibana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: kibana
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.2.0
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
        env:
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
            value: http://elastic.****************:80
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5601
          name: kibana
          protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: *************
  labels:
    component: kibana
spec:
  selector:
    component: kibana
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: "TCP"
    name: "http"
    targetPort: 5601
```

---

I am using an ingress but Kibana comlpetely ignores the ELASTICSEARCH_URL value when i try to deploy the 7.2.0 but it works when i rollback to the 6.8.1. I don't know if this methode is no longer supported on the 7.2.0, i've been all over trying to find some documentation but no luck.

Comment: Please give the full pod logs on start and also the elasticsearch deployment, logs, and any relevant `ConfigMaps`.

Comment: Is elasticsearch status green

Comment: @AndyShinn i added elasticsearch end kibana's deployments, services, configmaps and logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Kibana 7.0 `elasticsearch.url` is no longer valid and it is now `elasticsearch.hosts`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.x/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_literal_elasticsearch_url_literal_is_no_longer_valid.

The environment variables translate to these settings names. In this case, the new environment variable would be `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS`. See the example at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.2/docker.html.

Answer (score 0):

update ingest service dns name in ELASTICSEARCH_URL as shown below. assuming kibana and es are running in the same k8s cluster

```
          - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
            value: http://ingest.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:9200
```

update the correct namespace they are running in

Comment: Yes kibana and elasticsearch are running on the same K8s cluster. For the ingest service dns name that is exactly what i have (pointing to port 80 instead). What i can't understand is that i have the same setup with kibana & es 6.8.1 on another namespace and the are working just fine but for some reason kibana won't connect to es when i change the version to 7.2

Comment: share output from kubectl get svc ingest -oyaml

Comment: and from kubectl get ep ingest -oyaml

Comment: add it to response

Comment: i've added them

Answer (score 0):

change your env key from ELASTICSEARCH_URL to ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS

Comment: This is a repeat of the accepted answer from over a year ago.

Comment: i'm just answer